# Upgrading to cedar-14 when deploying via the heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku

I tried to migrate my app to cedar-14 stack, but when i do:

**heroku stack:set cedar-14**

i ve got the message: **stack:set` is not a heroku command**

What can i do please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please use following command to move from cedar to cedar-14

```
heroku stack:migrate cedar-14 -a <app name>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates your version of the heroku toolbelt doesn't know this command. You should update to the latest version.

You can check the version you have installed with the `heroku version` command:

```
heroku version
heroku-toolbelt/3.42.20 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
heroku-cli/4.26.1-bf7a4d8 (amd64-darwin) go1.5.1
```

The `heroku update` command should update you to the latest version. If that doesn't work, try reinstalling it from scratch: https://toolbelt.heroku.com/

You also need to make sure you aren't using the gem version of the toolbelt, which has been deprecated for several years. Uninstall it with the `gem uninstall heroku` command.

Comment: Hello i tried : gem uninstall heroku  then "heroku version"

Comment: Hello i tried gem uninstall heroku then "heroku version" but i don't see "heroku-toolbet/x.y.z" ???  then i tried "wget -O- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh"  and now i ve got error like " (Gem::LoadError)" and i can't do heroku command ??  What can i do please ???

Comment: What is the output of the `which heroku` command? Remove that executable and try reinstalling the toolbelt.

Comment: @DavidGautier did you find the solution.