# Heroku_can't upgrade to Cedar-14

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, cedar

As requested on Heroku, I am trying to upgrade from Cedar-10 to Cedar-14, but in vain.
On my console, When I execute

```
heroku stack:set cedar-14
```

I get this:

```
 `stack:set` is not a heroku command.
```

Even if I've already installed the latest version of heroku toolbelt as proposed [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33334287/upgrading-to-cedar-14-when-deploying-via-the-heroku) (I am on Windows), I get the same error message

Many thanks

Comment: What heroku version do you use ? Try `heroku version` in terminal

Comment: This one: "heroku-gem/2.35.0 (i386-mingw32) ruby/1.9.3";
Do I have to update ? many thanks

Comment: Yes, it's old, check https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command as posted in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your current heroku version isn't up to date.

Things you can try:

```
heroku update
```

If that doesn't work

```
gem uninstall heroku
```

Reinstall the gem or the heroku toolbelt

If that doesn't work:

```
which heroku
```

Delete the executable at the path listed by the above mentioned command

After that reinstall the heroku toolbelt

For more info check: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command