# heroku login doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I installed Heroku toolbelt for windows and now when I try to run heroku commands in the shell nothing happens.

```
user@canacher-pc MINGW32 ~
$ heroku login

user@canacher-pc MINGW32 ~
$ heroku version

user@canacher-pc MINGW32 ~
$ heroku create

user@canacher-pc MINGW32 ~
$
```

I notice that in the installation was include ruby v2.1.7 and I had previously installed ruby v1.9.3, I don't know if that a problem. I'm using windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the instructions at: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command

Also, read my answer at [Heroku_can't upgrade to Cedar-14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456254/heroku-cant-upgrade-to-cedar-14?noredirect=1#comment56656631_34456254)

Comment: Which instructions?