# Application Error on heroku app after deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, cedar

I have my `rails` application deployed on `heroku`. When I tried to push new changes on `heroku` they asked me to upgrade `cedar -14`.

Then, I ran this command

```
 heroku stack:set cedar-14 -a <app name>
```

after running this command  I deployed my app to `heroku`.After successful deployment when I try to run app through `url`. It shows `Application Error` and log says something like this...

```
: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
```

Comment: You can get logs from heroku with `heroku logs` from the command line.  Then you can see what actually happened with your app.  Heroku logs docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging

Comment: I ran `heroku logs` command. This line is showing in logs

    


 `2016-07-22T19:00:14.185165+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error       code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=www.tsn-dev.com request_id=5d0179f8-8f59-4fc8-a9b5-eebbffa558c1 fwd="110.93.205.130,162.158.92.168" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=`

I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: Not much I can think of.  I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456254/heroku-cant-upgrade-to-cedar-14.  Other stuff states it could be db not existing or not migrated, but if your app was alive on cedar 10, I can't imagine it's that.